# Map a union to a string literal union of the type names

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

I have a type like this (in this case, the user would be a custom interface):

```
export type ArgumentTypes = string | number | boolean | user;
```

now, I would like to have a type of

```
export type ArgumentTypeNames = "string" | "number" | "boolean" | "user";
```

I've tried to search around myself for a while, but I have not been able to find a way to get the name. I tried to do `${ArgumentTypes}` but that didn't work.

I'm pretty new to advanced types ( Mapped, conditional, and so on ) so I would love an explanation of the answer, or of potential solutions.

Comment: You can't do that without an explicit mapping of `string` to `"string"`, `number` to `"number"` etc. existing somewhere in your program

Comment: Thanks! Thats pretty much what i was looking for. Wether or not I had missed something that would make this possible

Comment: Okay, I'll make it the answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, as of today's version of TypeScript, you can't do that without an explicit mapping of `string` to `"string"`, `number` to `"number"` etc. existing somewhere in your program. The mapping might look like this:

```
interface TypeMapping {
  string: string;
  number: number;
  boolean: boolean;
  user: user;
}
```

However, not all is lost. You could make this mapping the source of truth, and derive other types from it:

```
type ArgumentTypeNames = keyof TypeMapping;
type ArgumentTypes = TypeMapping[ArgumentTypeNames];
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WvY7nm).*

Comment: Would I be able to extract the types from an interface like this, or would it be limited to the names?

Comment: You have missed your quoting in your interface, but you did put them on your playground, otherwise your just mapping `string = string`, and not `string = "string"`.. :)

Comment: @JanuZz_dk  It is extracting the Types..

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the edit, the last part was not in there when I first saw it. My bad

Comment: @Keith The identifiers to the left of ":" are property keys. In this case, they are strings; other possible values are numbers and symbols; other types are forbidden in this place

Comment: @JanuZz_dk My bad, should've notified you

Comment: Good point, personally I preferred your quoted version, as it makes it more obvious.